# Make a float div shift div in another-container when collide

Tags: css

Two columns of boxes, and sometimes, left-column boxes can be larger than the column, and have to move down rigth-column boxes to avoid collision.
Boxes of right or left column can be contained or not, but I don't know # of larger box. Anything can be floated, block or inline, etc.

```
I have this:
```

[image]

```
I want this:
```

[image]

Is this somehow possible with CSS only?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66d3jcL3/) (first screenshots)

Thanks!

Comment: CSS, I'm pretty sure, can't do this. I think you'd need Javascript.

Comment: With all weird behavious CSS can have, and for once I actualy want one… well, pretty shure it can! ;)

Comment: Paulie_D is right. You probably need jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Setting greens to `inline-block` and `float: left` on blues (and not their parents) works as expected. No JS ;)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66d3jcL3/9/) (I inverted blue and green in my attemps)

Comment: Great! I was finally right to believe in a no-JS solution ;) Thanks! (And thanks others for concerns!)